# Magento's modal-popup's don't scroll on Safari

Tags: magento2, css, browser

I have discovered that Magento's modal-popup's do not scroll on safari.

You can see this is you log into a Magento 2 demo store with a user which has a saved shipping address. Go to the checkout and click on the New Address button.

[image]

You will notice that eventhough the .modal-popup has a CSS rule for `overflow-y: auto` it does not scroll.

I've search online and this seems to be a common issue on Safari, but none of the solutions I have read of work for Magetno.

Answer (score 3):

Check PR: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21150 for the fix.

It's an issue with the `pointer-events` property. Just need to set it to `auto`

Comment: pointer-events: none; is the issue. Should be "auto", as sticky headers are obstructive on mobile screens, especially when they contain only titles, lol

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been picked up and I believe a fix issued on Magento V 2.3 as follows: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21147

However, I see no fix for 2.2. I have issues when a customer logged into their account cannot add an address as it is a modal form. Clicking text entry boxes (ie phone number) at the bottom of the screen allows the form to scroll up but is far from ideal. Has anyone seen a patch for 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the modal-inner-wrap div to have `height: 100%`, makes the inner div scrollable which is a better UX but still different from how it works on chrome without.

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .modal-popup.modal-slide._inner-scroll .modal-inner-wrap {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```